# where does maven tomcat7 plugin stores/reads dependency jars?

Tags: tomcat7, maven-3, maven-tomcat-plugin, maven-profiles

I'm trying to override a dependency version through a maven profile. I did a test installing the war and it works. The problem is when I run the war using maven tomcat plugin. I wanted to check which version of the jar is used, but I have no idea where it reads the jars from. I cannot find anything useful on available documentation..
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this page will help you to understand: http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/tomcat7-maven-plugin/adjust-embedded-tomcat-version.html

Use the dependencies section in plugin section
HTH

Comment: Hi Olamy, thanks for your answer, but I'm afraid I didn't explain myself properly. I wan't to check the version of a jar that would be placed on the lib folder in a regular war build. The jar I'm trying to check its version is a war dependency, not the tomcat jar version..

Comment: Oh ok sorry for the bad answer. The plugin use same versions as for packaging war. you should see jars used with using -X flag on command line.

Comment: Well I have a complex profile setup, so that wouldn't be so simple.. but given I have no other option, I will have to give it a try